# Why is the output of print in python2 and python3 different with the same string?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

In python2:

```
$ python2 -c 'print "\x08\x04\x87\x18"' | hexdump -C
00000000  08 04 87 18 0a                                    |.....|
00000005
```

In python3:

```
$ python3 -c 'print("\x08\x04\x87\x18")' | hexdump -C
00000000  08 04 c2 87 18 0a                                 |......|
00000006
```

Why does it have the byte `"\xc2"` here?

**Edit**:

I think when the string have a non-ascii character, python3 will append the byte `"\xc2"` to the string. (as @Ashraful Islam said)

So how can I avoid this in python3?

Comment: Any other examples? Can you find a pattern?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
import sys
for i in range(128, 256):
    sys.stdout.write(chr(i))
```

Run this with Python 2 and look at the result with `hexdump -C`:

```
00000000  80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87  88 89 8a 8b 8c 8d 8e 8f  |................|
```

Et cetera. No surprises; 128 bytes from `0x80` to `0xff`.

Do the same with Python 3:

```
00000000  c2 80 c2 81 c2 82 c2 83  c2 84 c2 85 c2 86 c2 87  |................|
...
00000070  c2 b8 c2 b9 c2 ba c2 bb  c2 bc c2 bd c2 be c2 bf  |................|
00000080  c3 80 c3 81 c3 82 c3 83  c3 84 c3 85 c3 86 c3 87  |................|
...
000000f0  c3 b8 c3 b9 c3 ba c3 bb  c3 bc c3 bd c3 be c3 bf  |................|
```

To summarize:

- Everything from `0x80` to `0xbf` has `0xc2` prepended.
- Everything from `0xc0` to `0xff` has bit 6 set to zero and has `0xc3` prepended.

So, what’s going on here?

In Python 2, strings are ASCII and no conversion is done. Tell it to
write something outside the 0-127 ASCII range, it says “okey-doke!” and
just writes those bytes. Simple.

In Python 3, strings are *Unicode*. When non-ASCII characters are
written, they must be *encoded* in some way. The default encoding is
UTF-8.

So, how are these values encoded in UTF-8?

Code points from `0x80` to `0x7ff` are encoded as follows:

```
110vvvvv 10vvvvvv
```

Where the 11 `v` characters are the bits of the code point.

Thus:

```
0x80                 hex
1000 0000            8-bit binary
000 1000 0000        11-bit binary
00010 000000         divide into vvvvv vvvvvv
11000010 10000000    resulting UTF-8 octets in binary
0xc2 0x80            resulting UTF-8 octets in hex

0xc0                 hex
1100 0000            8-bit binary
000 1100 0000        11-bit binary
00011 000000         divide into vvvvv vvvvvv
11000011 10000000    resulting UTF-8 octets in binary
0xc3 0x80            resulting UTF-8 octets in hex
```

So that’s why you’re getting a `c2` before `87`.

How to avoid all this in Python 3? Use the `bytes` type.

Comment: Use the `bytes` type how?  I'm looking for a canonical duplicate for questions like [why the NOP sled not working properly is there any protection for nop sled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67241949) and [outputing nop (\x90) to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61207044) for people using Python to make shellcode, for some reason instead of `nasm -fbin`.  Just with `sys.stdout.buffer.write` as shown in Mark's answer?  It seems `import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\x90" * 63 + b"more stuff")` does work; no easier way to output with the `bytes` type?

Answer (score 6):

Python 2's default string type is byte strings.  Byte strings are written `"abc"` while Unicode strings are written `u"abc"`.

Python 3's default string type is Unicode strings.  Byte strings are written as `b"abc"` while Unicode strings are written `"abc"` (`u"abc"` still works, too).  since there are millions of Unicode characters, printing them as bytes requires an encoding ([UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) in your case) which requires multiple bytes per code point.

First use a byte string in Python 3 to get the same Python 2 type.  Then, because Python 3's `print` expects Unicode strings, use `sys.stdout.buffer.write` to write to the raw stdout interface, which expects byte strings.

```
python3 -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"\x08\x04\x87\x18")'
```

Note that if writing to a file, there are similar issues.  For no encoding translation, open files in binary mode `'wb'` and write byte strings.